# Yii2 gridview filter a computed column not in database

Tags: php, yii2

for example I have added a column distance with `attribute` as distance.
The result for different rows may vary 5 to 20miles. the query is like if the result is less than 5miles it shows null.

Now I want to pre-filter the records to show only those records which have a distance of less than 5Km or say the result is null.

how I can achieve it.

the attribute code is like this:

```
[
            'attribute'=>'distance',
            'value'=>function($data){              
               $volunteer = UserProfile::findOne(['user_id'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);

                $lat_add = $volunteer->lat_add;
                $long_add = $volunteer->long_add;
                $db = Yii::$app->db;
                $query = "SELECT id,(
                3959 * acos 
                (cos ( radians($lat_add))
                * cos( radians( lat_add )) 
                * cos( radians( long_add) - radians($long_add))
                 + sin ( radians($lat_add) ) 
                * sin( radians( lat_add)))) 
                AS distance FROM user_profile where `user_id` = $data->posted_by 
                HAVING distance < 8.04672 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";
                $result = $db->createCommand($query)->queryOne();                
                return $result['distance'];
            }
        ],
```

Comment: please clarify your question,  you have problem in sql? and are you trying to calculate distance based on latitude and longitude of 2 points? or you are getting value but you cant put 5km condition?

Comment: no there is no issue with sql it is working perfectly. As I said I am getting results in the range of more than 5miles i.e. 8.04672. so when the result is empty I don't want to show that row/record in gridview.

Comment: gridview has rowOptions , function in which you can do this check, if distance is null then hide it, or you can do this in $dataprovider, put this check in the main query,

Comment: I want to hid the entire row. I tried in dataProvider, but I am getting there is no such column. as for rowOption - not sure how I can use it to hide the row.

Comment: Update your question and add the related  action so we ca se how you prepare  the dataProvider ..

Answer (score 1):

If you need not to show rows  with null distance
Instead of repeat the query for each row  result value in gridView 
In your action you should select only the rows  with this feature  eg:

using a proper sqlDatProvider

```
   "SELECT col1
            , col2
            , col3 
            , id
            , ( 3959 * acos 
                (cos ( radians($lat_add))
                * cos( radians( lat_add )) 
                * cos( radians( long_add) - radians($long_add))
                 + sin ( radians($lat_add) ) 
                * sin( radians( lat_add)))) 
                AS distance
     FROM user_profile where `user_id` = $data->posted_by 
     HAVING distance < 8.04672 7
     ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";
```

In this way your query return only the rows you want show

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge - I will try that, not used sqlDataProvider before. But I was able to resolve the same in a different way. for example I created a function in the Model `getDistanceMiles` and in the gridview in the closure included that function and in controller `$dataProvider->query->andWhere("$model->distanceMiles < 8.04672");`

Comment: @Joshi  .. but this way you must hide the rows that you don't need ..  with my suggestion you have not rows to hide.... you just need  a proper query sql and use it in a sqldataprovider

Comment: can you take a look here for sqldataprovider - I am getting error for search - https://stackoverflow.com/q/67034320/1124993